# Import from AutoCAD DXF

Tags: import

Evening all! I'm new to Blender, and trying to import an AutoCAD DXF file. This is possible according to the online manual (File=>Import/Export=>AutoCAD DXF), but not visible in my menu options. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure, that you have "Import AutoCAD DXF Format" enabled in Edit ⇾ Preferences ⇾ Add-ons

[image: s]

Comment: Job done. Many thanks!